# Supported pyomo free solvers for (non-convex) quadratic programming

Tags: solver, pyomo, quadratic-programming, nonconvex-programming, open-source

Any one had the chance to use pyomo with free/open-source solvers that handle quadratic optimization problems, which they could be convex or not, but preferably as general as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For guaranteed solutions, BONMIN can solve convex MINLPs, and COUENNE can solve general non-convex MINLPs. Both use the ASL (.nl) format, so they work out of the box with Pyomo. IPOPT can also find local optima for non-convex NLP (including quadratic) problems.

Comment: did you get chance to try them all? what would you recommend to start with?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do, Couenne is the most fool-proof one because it can handle all problem types.